# What tool to use to draw file tree diagram

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems, diagram

Given a file tree - a directory with directories in it etc, how would you write a script to create a diagram of the file-tree as a graphic file that I can embed in a word processor document.
I prefer vector (SVG, EPS, EMF...) files.
The tool must run on Windows,  but preferably cross-platform.
The tool may be commercial but preferably free.

Update 2012-02-20.
The question was related to a documentation sub project. I had to explan where files (in particular resources and configuration files) reside.
I ended up with using dos tree command. I both screen grabbed the result (for short folders) AND for longer folders I redirected to a text file, which I then edited. For example if a subfolder contained 20 similarly typed files that individually were not important to the point I was making, I left just two and replaced the rest with one ... line. I then printed out the file to console again and screen grabbed it.
Before screen grabbing I had to modify foreground color to black and background color to white, to look better and save ink in a document should that be printed.

It is very surprising that there is no better tool for it. If I had time, I'd write a Visio Extension or may be some command line that produces SVG. SVG being HTML5 substandard, would even allow painless inclusion into online documentation.

Update 2017-10-17.
I am sorry that this question was removed as not belonging to SO. So I have re-worded it. I need a script - not a WYSIWYG tool. So any scripting language or library is ok. So it is a code - writing question, and I believe belongs to SO.

Comment: Why is this question closed? There are programming DSL's to draw trees: e.g. tools like graphviz which can solve this "programmatically".

Comment: I'm going to re-open this (tentatively) because if it were a simple "how do I show what's on screen", he would have asked for a screen grabber. If he wants to draw it, it's probably for a design doc or presentation, hence he'll be programming at some point.

Comment: Agreed.  I have needed this same type of functionality before and have resorted to faking it with Visio.  Needed it for EU documentation.  Definitely was code related.

Comment: VERY Stupid, to close this as off-topic. I too have found a need for something.. SO loves to censor.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is off topic here. I understand the reason why. Thanks to all those who aswered, it was helpful.  To clarify, I needed a diagram to include into documentation of the project tree. Screenshot does not cut it because the whole tree is longer than fits one screen.

Comment: From [a similar question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147467/351462), try using http://jsfiddle.net/WjAk9/7/embedded/result/

Comment: `sudo snap install tree` or visit https://snapcraft.io/tree

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Copying and pasting from the MS-DOS `tree` command might also work for you. Examples:

**tree**

```
C:\Foobar>tree
C:.
├───FooScripts
├───barconfig
├───Baz
│   ├───BadBaz
│   └───Drop
...
```

**tree /F**

```
C:\Foobar>tree
C:.
├───FooScripts
│    foo.sh
├───barconfig
│    bar.xml
├───Baz
│   ├───BadBaz
│   │    badbaz.xml
│   └───Drop
...
```

**tree /A**

```
C:\Foobar>tree /A
C:.
+---FooScripts
+---barconfig
+---Baz
¦   +---BadBaz
¦   \---Drop
...
```

**tree /F /A**

```
C:\Foobar>tree /A
C:.
+---FooScripts
¦    foo.sh
+---barconfig
¦    bar.xml
+---Baz
¦   +---BadBaz
¦   ¦    badbaz.xml
¦   \---Drop
...
```

#### Syntax <sup>[[source](https://www.computerhope.com/treehlp.htm)]</sup>

`tree` [`drive:`][`path`] [`/F`] [`/A`]

> `drive:\path` — Drive and directory containing disk for display of directory structure, without listing files.
>
> `/F` — Include all files living in every directory.
>
> `/A` — Replace graphic characters used for linking lines with ext characters , instead of graphic characters. `/a` is used with code pages that do not support graphic characters and to send output to printers that do not properly interpret graphic characters.

Comment: Good idea, but if there are files/folders with accented letters, they will be in OEM charset, not Ansi one. Probably a non-issue for most (English speaking at least) users, of course. Same for semi-graphic chars.

Comment: Linux also has a "tree" command like this, I've just discovered after checking out this Stack Overflow question. Thanks for pointing out the name I should look for!  "tree -A" is how to create the tree using pretty drawing-characters; plain "tree" just confines itself to ASCII.

Comment: Or save it straight to a file:
`tree > file_structure.txt`
I know this works on Unix systems. I don't know if it works on Windows as well.

Comment: is there a way to limit the number of files shown ? for example I have hundreds of file in a subfolder, all with the same "name logic". i'ld like to display just a few of them and display the number of files, but not all files.

Answer (score 19):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) - from the web page:

> The Graphviz layout programs take descriptions of graphs in a simple text language, and make diagrams in several useful formats such as images and SVG for web pages, Postscript for inclusion in PDF or other documents; or display in an interactive graph browser. (Graphviz also supports GXL, an XML dialect.)

It's the simplest and most productive tool I've found to create a variety of boxes-and-lines diagrams. I have and use Visio and OmniGraffle, but there's always the temptation to make "just one more adjustment".

It's also quite easy to write code to produce the "dot file" format that Graphiz consumes, so automated diagram production is also nicely within reach.

Answer (score 5):

Why could you not just make a file structure on the Windows file system and populate it with your desired names, then use a screen grabber like HyperSnap (or the ubiquitous Alt-PrtScr) to capture a section of the Explorer window.

I did this when 'demoing' an internet application which would have collapsible sections, I just had to create files that looked like my desired entries.

HyperSnap gives JPGs at least (probably others but I've never bothered to investigate).

Or you could screen capture the icons +/- from Explorer and use them within MS Word Draw itself to do your picture, but I've never been able to get MS Word Draw to behave itself properly.

Comment: Explorer doesn't show nested folders, only the top level.

Answer (score 5):

As promised, here is my Cairo version. I scripted it with Lua, using lfs to walk the directories. I love these little challenges, as they allow me to explore APIs I wanted to dig for quite some time...
lfs and LuaCairo are both cross-platform, so it should work on other systems (tested on French WinXP Pro SP3).

I made a first version drawing file names as I walked the tree. Advantage: no memory overhead. Inconvenience: I have to specify the image size beforehand, so listings are likely to be cut off.

So I made this version, first walking the directory tree, storing it in a Lua table. Then, knowing the number of files, creating the canvas to fit (at least vertically) and drawing the names.
You can easily switch between PNG rendering and SVG one. Problem with the latter: Cairo generates it at low level, drawing the letters instead of using SVG's text capability. Well, at least, it guarantees accurate rending even on systems without the font. But the files are bigger... Not really a problem if you compress it after, to have a .svgz file.
Or it shouldn't be too hard to generate the SVG directly, I used Lua to generate SVG in the past.

```
-- LuaFileSystem <http://www.keplerproject.org/luafilesystem/>
require"lfs"
-- LuaCairo <http://www.dynaset.org/dogusanh/>
require"lcairo"
local CAIRO = cairo


local PI = math.pi
local TWO_PI = 2 * PI

--~ local dirToList = arg[1] or "C:/PrgCmdLine/Graphviz"
--~ local dirToList = arg[1] or "C:/PrgCmdLine/Tecgraf"
local dirToList = arg[1] or "C:/PrgCmdLine/tcc"
-- Ensure path ends with /
dirToList = string.gsub(dirToList, "([^/])$", "%1/")
print("Listing: " .. dirToList)
local fileNb = 0

--~ outputType = 'svg'
outputType = 'png'

-- dirToList must have a trailing slash
function ListDirectory(dirToList)
  local dirListing = {}
  for file in lfs.dir(dirToList) do
    if file ~= ".." and file ~= "." then
      local fileAttr = lfs.attributes(dirToList .. file)
      if fileAttr.mode == "directory" then
        dirListing[file] = ListDirectory(dirToList .. file .. '/')
      else
        dirListing[file] = ""
      end
      fileNb = fileNb + 1
    end
  end
  return dirListing
end

--dofile[[../Lua/DumpObject.lua]] -- My own dump routine
local dirListing = ListDirectory(dirToList)
--~ print("\n" .. DumpObject(dirListing))
print("Found " .. fileNb .. " files")

--~ os.exit()

-- Constants to change to adjust aspect
local initialOffsetX = 20
local offsetY = 50
local offsetIncrementX = 20
local offsetIncrementY = 12
local iconOffset = 10

local width = 800 -- Still arbitrary
local titleHeight = width/50
local height = offsetIncrementY * (fileNb + 1) + titleHeight
local outfile = "CairoDirTree." .. outputType

local ctxSurface
if outputType == 'svg' then
  ctxSurface = cairo.SvgSurface(outfile, width, height)
else
  ctxSurface = cairo.ImageSurface(CAIRO.FORMAT_RGB24, width, height)
end
local ctx = cairo.Context(ctxSurface)

-- Display a file name
-- file is the file name to display
-- offsetX is the indentation
function DisplayFile(file, bIsDir, offsetX)
  if bIsDir then
    ctx:save()
    ctx:select_font_face("Sans", CAIRO.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO.FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)
    ctx:set_source_rgb(0.5, 0.0, 0.7)
  end

  -- Display file name
  ctx:move_to(offsetX, offsetY)
  ctx:show_text(file)

  if bIsDir then
    ctx:new_sub_path() -- Position independent of latest move_to
    -- Draw arc with absolute coordinates
    ctx:arc(offsetX - iconOffset, offsetY - offsetIncrementY/3, offsetIncrementY/3, 0, TWO_PI)
    -- Violet disk
    ctx:set_source_rgb(0.7, 0.0, 0.7)
    ctx:fill()
    ctx:restore() -- Restore original settings
  end

  -- Increment line offset
  offsetY = offsetY + offsetIncrementY
end

-- Erase background (white)
ctx:set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
ctx:paint()

--~ ctx:set_line_width(0.01)

-- Draw in dark blue
ctx:set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.3)
ctx:select_font_face("Sans", CAIRO.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO.FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)
ctx:set_font_size(titleHeight)
ctx:move_to(5, titleHeight)
-- Display title
ctx:show_text("Directory tree of " .. dirToList)

-- Select font for file names
ctx:select_font_face("Sans", CAIRO.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
ctx:set_font_size(10)
offsetY = titleHeight * 2

-- Do the job
function DisplayDirectory(dirToList, offsetX)
  for k, v in pairs(dirToList) do
--~ print(k, v)
    if type(v) == "table" then
      -- Sub-directory
      DisplayFile(k, true, offsetX)
      DisplayDirectory(v, offsetX + offsetIncrementX)
    else
      DisplayFile(k, false, offsetX)
    end
  end
end

DisplayDirectory(dirListing, initialOffsetX)

if outputType == 'svg' then
    cairo.show_page(ctx)
else
  --cairo.surface_write_to_png(ctxSurface, outfile)
  ctxSurface:write_to_png(outfile)
end

ctx:destroy()
ctxSurface:destroy()

print("Found " .. fileNb .. " files")
```

Of course, you can change the styles. I didn't draw the connection lines, I didn't saw it as necessary. I might add them optionally later.

Answer (score 2):

The advice to use Graphviz is good: you can generate the dot file and it will do the hard work of measuring strings, doing the layout, etc. Plus it can output the graphs in lot of formats, including vector ones.

I found a Perl program doing precisely that, in a mailing list, but I just can't find it back! I copied the sample dot file and studied it, since I don't know much of this declarative syntax and I wanted to learn a bit more.

Problem: with latest Graphviz, I have errors (or rather, warnings, as the final diagram is generated), both in the original graph and the one I wrote (by hand). Some searches shown this error was found in old versions and disappeared in more recent versions. Looks like it is back.

I still give the file, maybe it can be a starting point for somebody, or maybe it is enough for your needs (of course, you still have to generate it).

```
digraph tree
{
  rankdir=LR;

  DirTree [label="Directory Tree" shape=box]

  a_Foo_txt [shape=point]
  f_Foo_txt [label="Foo.txt", shape=none]
  a_Foo_txt -> f_Foo_txt

  a_Foo_Bar_html [shape=point]
  f_Foo_Bar_html [label="Foo Bar.html", shape=none]
  a_Foo_Bar_html -> f_Foo_Bar_html

  a_Bar_png [shape=point]
  f_Bar_png [label="Bar.png", shape=none]
  a_Bar_png -> f_Bar_png

  a_Some_Dir [shape=point]
  d_Some_Dir [label="Some Dir", shape=ellipse]
  a_Some_Dir -> d_Some_Dir

  a_VBE_C_reg [shape=point]
  f_VBE_C_reg [label="VBE_C.reg", shape=none]
  a_VBE_C_reg -> f_VBE_C_reg

  a_P_Folder [shape=point]
  d_P_Folder [label="P Folder", shape=ellipse]
  a_P_Folder -> d_P_Folder

  a_Processing_20081117_7z [shape=point]
  f_Processing_20081117_7z [label="Processing-20081117.7z", shape=none]
  a_Processing_20081117_7z -> f_Processing_20081117_7z

  a_UsefulBits_lua [shape=point]
  f_UsefulBits_lua [label="UsefulBits.lua", shape=none]
  a_UsefulBits_lua -> f_UsefulBits_lua

  a_Graphviz [shape=point]
  d_Graphviz [label="Graphviz", shape=ellipse]
  a_Graphviz -> d_Graphviz

  a_Tree_dot [shape=point]
  f_Tree_dot [label="Tree.dot", shape=none]
  a_Tree_dot -> f_Tree_dot

  {
    rank=same;
    DirTree -> a_Foo_txt -> a_Foo_Bar_html -> a_Bar_png -> a_Some_Dir -> a_Graphviz [arrowhead=none]
  }
  {
    rank=same;
    d_Some_Dir -> a_VBE_C_reg -> a_P_Folder -> a_UsefulBits_lua [arrowhead=none]
  }
  {
    rank=same;
    d_P_Folder -> a_Processing_20081117_7z [arrowhead=none]
  }
  {
    rank=same;
    d_Graphviz -> a_Tree_dot [arrowhead=none]
  }
}

> dot -Tpng Tree.dot -o Tree.png
Error: lost DirTree a_Foo_txt edge
Error: lost a_Foo_txt a_Foo_Bar_html edge
Error: lost a_Foo_Bar_html a_Bar_png edge
Error: lost a_Bar_png a_Some_Dir edge
Error: lost a_Some_Dir a_Graphviz edge
Error: lost d_Some_Dir a_VBE_C_reg edge
Error: lost a_VBE_C_reg a_P_Folder edge
Error: lost a_P_Folder a_UsefulBits_lua edge
Error: lost d_P_Folder a_Processing_20081117_7z edge
Error: lost d_Graphviz a_Tree_dot edge
```

I will try another direction, using Cairo, which is also able to export a number of formats. It is more work (computing positions/offsets) but the structure is simple, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Steve DeRose has a Perlscript making file-structure -> dot file at http://www.derose.net/steve/utilities/