# Showing webpage from parent directory using object-Tag

Tags: php, html, path, raspberry-pi, webserver

I want to show a website, which is in the parent directory of the *html* (Webserver) folder. My file structure looks like this:

```
├───www
│   ├───html
|   |   └───index.html
│   └───clients (Folder with other websites)
|       └───website_1
|       └───website_2
```

The object-Tag is located in the index.html. I tried using:

```
<object type="text/html" data="../clients/website_1/index.php" width="100%" height="100%" style="overflow:auto;">
```

but it didn't show up. If I use a html- or php-file, which is in the html-Folder, it will be displayed correctly. But when I try to choose the *website_1*-folder, I just get a white screen.

---

The reason for this is that I do not want to be able to access the folder via a domain or IP. That's why I want the clients-folder to be outside of the webserver.

Just to make sure, the "www-data"-user has enough permissions for both folders:

```
drwx--S--- 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 26 17:09 clients
drwx------ 7 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 26 17:11 html
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: how do you make those directory diagrams @Jan

Comment: I just copied an example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347551/what-tool-to-use-to-draw-file-tree-diagram) from another question and adjusted it to suit for my case.

Comment: Is that permission for me to copy yours? @Jan

Comment: Actually, the tree diagram from the link i posted above was an extract of the "tree"-command in the cmd. So I don't think you need a special permission to copy it.

Comment: Have you checked if the server user has access to that folder?

Comment: Just to make show, the user has the same permissions for both folders:
clients-folder: "drwx--S---"  html-folder: "drwx------". But it still doesnt work.

Comment: I think i solved a part of my problem. There's something similar in the Apache-Doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html. It describes my problem very good, but I couldn't use it, because I don't want the folder to be reachable by the IP/domain.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by *I do not want to be able to access the folder via a domain or IP.*?

Comment: For example, you can reach my website at "test.com". That's where I want to show the object-Tag. In case you know HTML, you can find out via pressing F12, where the websites-folder is located. When you get the path, you can simply copy & paste it behind "test.com" and you're on the real page.