# If index.html and javascript not in the same folder, js does not work. Otherwise, it does

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I've this simple `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert("Hello World");
    </script>
    It's
    <script src="/js/date.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

which should recall `date.js`

```
document.write(new Date());
```

But unfortunately the date is not printed by the javascript.

- What's wrong?

Note that if I put `date.js` in the same folder of `index.html` (that  is`WEB-INF`), if I write `<script src="date.js"></script>` it works properly.

**EDIT**: This is the Project's hierarchy: [Project's hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6JRK.png) and this is the output: [Bad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak0DF.png)

Comment: Does the alert show up? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Hey, it should work if you change the path to `<script src="../Source Packages/js/date.js"></script>`

If source packages is a folder of course

Comment: your javascript file is in different location. so the relative address from where your index.html is : ""../Source Packages/js/date.js"". change the src property to the correct address and you will be fine.

Comment: If I understand the folder structure right: this `<script src="./js/date.js"></script>` or this `<script src="js/date.js"></script>` should work. Also you are missing close `</html>` tag in the markup.

Comment: The alert shows up correctly and if I change date.js location and putting in the same location of the index.html, date.js works properly, but I don't want them to be in the same package

Comment: @ambianBeing your solution does not work

Comment: @HeyBoo Have mentioned that if I understood the directory structure correctly. Could you edit the heirarchy to be presented in the question to like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347577/6082280) . Is the **js folder** not in the same directory as `index.html`. Is it inside **Source Packages** folder.

Comment: js folder is in src package folder

Comment: @HeyBoo Are you calling src as Source Packages in the question (if yes, that is little misleading). Would suggest to please post a screenshot of the directory structure in the question to provide a better visibility.

Comment: Just done it: post edited with further information

Comment: This solution does not work :(

Comment: @HeyBoo Since I tested it exact folder structure it worked as one of the asnwers suggest too (we cannot reproduce this). I think your js file is in some nested package or something (Why?). I suggest what you can do to debug is.. bring that js file to same directory as `index.html` and then move the `js` file one by one to the directory `/js` while changing the `src` (helpers: `./` same directory and `../` one directory backwards and so) this way you might find what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "../" to "go backwards" in folders so it would be

```
<script src="../Source Packages/js/date.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tested it and it works just nice.
Edit: Do you have your .js inside a zip or something like that?

Comment: Check out my "edit" section in this post to see the structure of my project: .js file is put in a directory called js

Comment: yes, i saw, but is that a zip or just a folder? the icon is different

Comment: It is a package created via "new->package"