# IntelliJ IDEA find usage for multiple projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In multiple project, IDEA can't find the all usages of the common project method and just found one of them which uses it. How to find usage across projects?

The version:

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition `2022.2.3`

gradle-`4.1`

The project:

[image: projct folder]

We can see the usage shows just the `pj-serviceA` project, but `pj-serviceB` is also using the pj-common method.

code:

*pj-common*:

```
package com.pj.common;

public class StringUtil {
    public static void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

*pj-serviceA*:

```
package com.pj.serviceA;

import com.pj.common.StringUtil;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringUtil.print("A");
    }
}
```

*pj-serviceB*:

```
package com.pj.serviceB;

import com.pj.common.StringUtil;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringUtil.print("B");
    }
}
```

the `pj-serviceA` and `pj-serviceB` all can run.

The problem:

[image: only found one project]

I want to find all the usages.

I invalidate all the caches, but can't solve it.

The project structure:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The running result:

[image]
[image]

If it's not clear yet, I'll put the code on GitHub on the weekend and post the link.

Github:
https://github.com/xiaotanwo/pj

Comment: The only reason that comes to mind is possibly a version difference : common is at version 2, service A uses version 2 of common but B uses version 1. Otherwise, without the project, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Common version is same, the project is new for this problem.

Both serviceA and serviceB, the build.gradle are the following

dependencies {
    compile project(":pj-common")
}

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without a project. Maybe you could use the IDE main menu `Help | Contact Support` to contact the IDEA support team with a sample project attached for checking. Normally, you should create a multi-module Gradle project with a parent module and include the common, serviceA, serviceB modules in it and let the serviceA and serviceB depend on the common module so the Find Usage would work.

Comment: Could you show, please, the whole structure of the project with the usage, e.g. [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347551/8370915) or [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61565622/8370915) (tree) with content inside each of class accordingly (instead of screen)? It'd would be more informative to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I add more details. If it's not clear yet, I'll put the code on GitHub on the weekend and post the link.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced this specific [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317570/Cannot-find-all-usages-of-base-method-in-Project-Files) using Java `8` & Gradle `4.1`/`7.1` & Windows `10`.

Used & tested `Intellij IDEA` versions:

`Intellij IDEA` version `2023.1` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2022.3.3` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2022.2.5` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2022.1.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2021.3.3` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2021.2.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2021.1.3` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2020.3.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2020.2.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2020.1.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2019.3.5` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2019.2.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2019.1.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2018.3.6` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2018.2.8` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (displays only one of the presented methods)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2018.1.8` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2017.3.7` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2017.2.7` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2017.1.6` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2016.3.8` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2016.2.5` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (doesn't display matches at all)

`Intellij IDEA` version `2016.1.4` Gradle `7.1` / Gradle `4.1` : (does not display matches at all)

As a possible workaround of it, you can use the combination `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F`:

[image]

And the result will be displaying all usages, as you need per requirements. By typing, for instance, either `StringUtil.print` or simply `print`. It depends on your needs, of course.

(For testing purposes I used `Intellij IDEA` version as `2022.3.3`)

*`Additional`* & *`helpful`* information:

- `Invalidate Caches` -> `Clear file system cache and Local History` didn't work for me.
- `Double Shift` didn't work for me also.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Double Shift is vaild, but it is just working in the static method. If the method is object(the variable name will be different in different code), and the  and other class also has the same name method. The double Shift find usages is not good in these conditions. I find the solution for this problem, make the three project as a project, it is the gradle problem. You can see it in new fix on my github. https://github.com/xiaotanwo/pj